# Rxjava - Iterate the list with batch

Tags: android, rx-java, rx-java2, rx-kotlin

i have a list of some strings, where i need to iterate the list in batch.
Example :

```
val list = ["a","b","c","d","e","f"]
Observable.fromIteratable(list)
          .map{
          //here i need to get 4 items at a time
          //like in first iteration i need to get ["a","b","c","d"]
          //in second iteration i need to get ["e","f"]
        }
```

Is there is any option to do perform this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

User [`buffer`](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/buffer.html)

> periodically gather items emitted by an Observable into bundles and emit these bundles rather than emitting the items one at a time

```
 val list = arrayOf("1", "2", "3", "4", "5")
 Observable.fromIterable(list.asIterable())
     .buffer(4)
     .map { stringList: MutableList<String> ->
       println("insideMap -> $stringList")
       return@map "wow $stringList"
     }
     .subscribe { value: String -> println("OnResult $value")}
```

```
//Output
insideMap -> [1, 2, 3, 4]
OnResult wow [1, 2, 3, 4]
insideMap -> [5]
OnResult wow [5]
```

> The **Buffer** operator transforms an Observable that emits items into an Observable that emits buffered collections of those items. There are a number of variants in the various language-specific implementations of Buffer that differ in how they choose which items go in which buffers.

Note that if the source Observable issues an **onError** notification, Buffer will pass on this notification immediately without first emitting the buffer it is in the process of assembling, even if that buffer contains items that were emitted by the source Observable before it issued the error notification.

Comment: Unless there is some real usecase behind this, I think it's overkill to use rxjava for the purpose.

Comment: Yeah, but I'm sure he/she must have used an analogy in his/her question :)